gio mount password with special characters
I want mount using well-known way
gio mount smb://<user>:<password>@<server>/<share>/

In my case
gio mount "smb://WORKGROUP;myuser:+B@e}F)q8tra@@192.168.1.199/"

I get warning
Authentication Required
Enter password for “192.168.1.199”:
It is because of my password +B@e}F)q8tra@ I try convert it using this converter to %2BB%40e%7DF%29q8tra%40 but without success... I try add symbol \ with different combinations without success.
I read topic. I only found dirty hack here
echo "+B@e}F)q8tra@" | gio mount "smb://WORKGROUP;myuser@192.168.1.199/"

With this hack works.
Ho do without hack?

You may have to convert special characters to HTML % formatting in order for using the special characters in the connection string.  I have to do this for my password for the workplace using CIFS directly on the command line (or provide a separate smb_credentials file that SMB speaks).

@ThomasWard like this %2BB%40e%7DF%29q8tra%40? I already described about it in my post...
